# Hive Array Type that contain Custom Object

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

Can hive array contain custom java objects? i.e. Lets say that there is a custom POJO  class called Car.java, can the hive table be defined as follows?

Create table X (arr: Array < Car >)

I know there is a bit of serialization and de-serialization to be done to make this happen, but just wanted to check.

The [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-ComplexTypes) just says data_type but not clear on the possible data type.

Comment: The data_type here refers to one of the primitive data type. You very well may not use Hive if there is a need to create and use derived and/or any complex data type.

Comment: @raunakjhawar, http://www.congiu.com/structured-data-in-hive-a-generic-udf-to-sort-arrays-of-structs/ -                                                                This shows an example of an array of Struct types.

Comment: Hi, the URL you have shared compliments the above statement. Again data types used in Hive have to be one of the primitive type i.e. you can define a column of data structure type Struct but the individual columns in the struct must adhere to the fundamental data types supported by Hive. Here you cannot create a user defined data type i.e. a field of type Car